# Does ajax loaded form require a captcha

Tags: jquery, load, captcha, spam-prevention

I know that captcha is used to project the submit of a submit. But I wonder if you are required to click a button in order to load the submit form, do you need the captcha on that form then?

Will the spam robots click on that button to load the form? Unless it is human spam which no way we can avoid I think!

For instance, this is my jquery,

```
$('#get-submit-form').click(function(){
   element.load('submit-form.php', function(){});
})
```

Comment: What if the bot goes directly to `submit-form.php`?

Comment: Can that happen?? The form is stored in the server and I thought a server can prevent the the spam bots accessing the root files directly - or have I been wrong??

Comment: How will the server differentiate between the bot and a regular user?

Answer (score 2):

A [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) *is designed to prevent automated tools -- aka SPAM bots -- from access.*

If AJAX (really just HTTP requests that don't cause a page reload) is allowed to work without such guards (or alternative limits such as mandatory authentication and accountablility) then clever/customized bots/tools *can spam freely*. As far as "is the CAPTCAH is required" depends on if the server requires it for a given operation.

Please note that a client-side only CAPTCHA is useless and even server-side CAPTCHAs can be [circumvented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA#Circumvention) -- one such circumvention vector is not requiring it ;-)

Happy coding.